# Scala: How to apply implicit parameters to the different scope?

Tags: scala

I can't find out why my implicits aren't in the scope. Here is a test:

```
package test

object Main extends App {
  import fp._

  def foo(a: Int)(implicit b: B0) = a + b.x
  print(foo(1))
}
```

Components in diff package:

```
package fp

trait Components {
  implicit val b0: B0 = B0(2)
}

object Components extends Components

sealed trait B
case class B0(x: Int) extends B
```

The error I got

```
could not find implicit value for parameter b: fp.B0
  print(foo(1))
           ^
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either do

```
import fp.Components._
```

or define the implicit value `b0` in an implicit scope such as inside the companion object of `B0` or the package object.

Here are some reading materials:

- https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html
- http://eed3si9n.com/implicit-parameter-precedence-again

Comment: Yeap, it helps. Thank you.